# By mesh randomly got skinny as I was working with it

Tags: mesh

So my mesh got super thin seemingly out of the blue as I was editing it (It actually happened twice). Even hitting undo doesn't solve it since it only undoes the previous actions I've done to it instead of fixing the thinned out model. The model is supposed to look like a giant crushing piston. I'll put a reference as to what it should look like along with the broken mesh. Let me know if there's a fix for this or if you need more info on the problem first

Broken Model: [image]

What the model is supposed to look like: [image]

Comment: Have you given it a modifier?